# Specify array wide constraint for scipy.optimize.fmin_coblya and scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp (using f_ieqcons) or any other method

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, mathematical-optimization

I am looking to specify some multivariate constraints on an optimization that are functional (e.g. max - min in array should be less that X, average of the solution array should be above Y, etc.), so I started with a simple constraint of all elements should be positive (so I could compare it to the results by specifying bounds).

Here is the set up: I have a target composition of a compound and I have an existing composition, I want to get as close as possible (as measured by the sum of the absolute values of the differences of element amounts) to the target recipe by altering the existing composition.

```
from numpy import array 
from scipy import optimize 
from functools import partial 
from pprint import pprint as pp
def allPositive(x):
    return(1 if all([True if xi >= 0 else False for xi in x]) else -1)
def allPositiveAsArray(x):
    return(all([1.0 if xi >= 0 else -1.0 for xi in x]))
def recipeDeviation(x, startComposition, recipeCompostion):
    return sum( map(abs,array(x) + array(startComposition) - array(recipeCompostion)))
startComposition = [1.0,4.0,12.0]
recipeCompostion = [7.0,4.0,10.0]
funcToMinimize = partial(recipeDeviation, startComposition = startComposition, recipeCompostion = recipeCompostion)

result_constrained_1 = optimize.fmin_cobyla(funcToMinimize ,[0.0]*len(startComposition), cons=[allPositive])  # fails and gives wrong number
result_constrained_2 = optimize.fmin_slsqp(funcToMinimize ,[0.0]*len(startComposition), bounds = [(0.0, float("inf"))]*len(startComposition))
result_constrained_3 = optimize.fmin_slsqp(funcToMinimize ,[0.0]*len(startComposition), f_ieqcons = allPositive )  # does not work
result_constrained_4 = optimize.fmin_slsqp(funcToMinimize ,[0.0]*len(startComposition), f_ieqcons = allPositiveAsArray )  # does not work
result_constrained_5 = optimize.fmin_slsqp(funcToMinimize ,[0.0]*len(startComposition), f_ieqcons = lambda x: 1.0 if x >=0.0 else -1.0  )  # does not work
```

The answer is [ 6.0,0.0,0.0] (under constraints).

For `fmin_cobyla` it fails but at least it tells me something went wrong: `COBYLA failed to find a solution: Did not converge to a solution satisfying the constraints. See`maxcv`for magnitude of violation.`

Specifying bounds gives the right solution on `fmin_slsqp` but it does not help me to generalize to workable functions. The options 3 and 4 give me the unconstrained result (which tells me the specification is wrong).

I would need an example of the syntax for specifying such constraints (perhaps using the example above) in a multivariate setting.

Comment: I usually try to prevent constraint functions to be non-differentiable. Most optimizers assume functions are smooth.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I wonder if there is something in python pre-packaged that combines global methods (like annealing) with constraints. I will dig for it when there is some free time. Thanks.

Comment: As a feasibility-check (in regards to some constraints) can already be NP-hard, this combination you ask for in the general-case is trouble.

Comment: From your description, I have a hunch this may be just an LP. To be sure one would first need to write down the mathematical optimization model (which is always a good idea before doing any coding).